# Displaying a div from an assigned meta_value when on a page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, metabox, post-meta

On my website I created a custom metabox that is being displayed in the post type "page". The metabox will display a checkbox and 4 url fields. The checkbox will control the visibility of a div (section#footerLinks) and the url fields will control the 4 links that will appear with the div links.

**Ability**

The checkbox once clicked (on) will display my div with the four links, once I uncheck the box (off) it will hide the div.

**The Problem**

When I click the checkbox on and fill in the custom fields information it works perfectly. But this gets assign to all of my pages not just the one I have assigned. If I click the checkbox "on" for another page it displays two of the same divs.

Is there a way I can have each page control the div independently and only display one div?

**Example**

Page 1 should display the div with its own information and hide on all other pages.

Page 2 should display the div with its own information and hide on all other pages.

Below is my code I am using the hide the div and control the meta_value of my checkbox selection on

```
 <?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'meta_key'      => '_cmb_linkCheckbox',
    'meta_value'    => 'On',
    'showposts'     =>  1,
 );
 $links = new WP_Query( $args );
 ?>
 <?php if ( $links->have_posts() ) : while ( $links->have_posts() ) : $links->the_post(); ?> 
 <section id="footerLinks">
  <article id="footerIcons">
     <ul>
        <li>
          <ul><!-- CONTACT US -->
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_contactURL", true); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/contactUs.png" /></a></li>
            <li><h4>Contact Us</h4></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul><!-- REQUEST INFO -->
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_requestURL", true); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/requestInfo.png" /></a></li>
            <li><h4>Rquest Info</h4></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul><!-- VISIT -->
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_visitURL", true); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/visit.png" /></a></li>
            <li><h4>Visit</h4></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul><!-- APPLY -->
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_applyURL", true); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/apply.png" /></a></li>
            <li><h4>Apply</h4></li>
          </ul>            
        </li>
     </ul>
  </article>   
  </section>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: if this is on a page and your intention is to show the links that belong to the current page, then you shouldn't be querying for anything or running the loop. your query is returning the first page regardless of what page you're currently on.

Comment: yeah I have been noticing this and have tired other solutions and nothing seems to be working. How would I go about this? @Milo

Comment: just delete the query and the loop and leave your markup and `get_post_meta` calls. `$post->ID` will then refer to the current page and not the page you queried for in the loop.

Comment: I tried that and it seems to still be calling from the first page @Milo Also if I delete the query how will I control the visibility of the div which is controlled by the checkbox? It needs to be hidden if the checkbox is not selected.

Comment: If there is another query elsewhere in the page, then you need [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) first to restore the current page data.

Comment: as of right now there isn't.

Comment: the div needs to be hidden when I have the checkbox off and if display when the checkbox is on @Milo

Comment: Where is this code placed ? From what I'm getting, it's placed in the footer, right ?

Comment: correct @cristian.raiber

Comment: You don't need a WP Query in the footer. Remove the code that holds the query. Replace get_post_meta with get_post_custom($post->ID); Paste a var_dump of get_post_custom($post->ID) in your question, pls.

Comment: if i remove this would I still be able to hide my div if the checkbox is not selected? @cristian.raiber

Comment: Yes, you'll still be able to hide your div. As @Milo said below, you should make sure the value returned by either get_post_meta or get_post_custom is the one you're looking for. In this case, you should be checking if the value for that meta_field is == 'on'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check if a meta value exists before outputting markup, then

```
if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_linkCheckbox', true ) ){
    ?>
    <section id="footerLinks">
        <?php // your markup... ?>
    </section>
    <?php
}
```

or if the value is "on":

```
if( 'on' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_linkCheckbox', true ) ){
    // etc..
}
```